# Eclipse not showing the team menu under windows -> preferences

Tags: eclipse

I want to change the default author and committer when using git which apparently i have to do under "window -> preferences -> team -> git ..." but i don't have the team option under preferences

[image: as you can see hear]

I just did a clean eclipse install of the newest version from the website. I use jdk 14.0.2 and my OS is an up to date windows 10.

Also i still get a "Could not chdir to home directory /home/jb7: No such file or directory" but at least i can push successfully again after the reinstall.

Comment: It is called "Version Control (Team)" these days and you do have that.

Comment: I love you!! Probably should have been able to figure that out myself. Thank you very much!